# What am I doing wrong in the below Prolog code

Tags: recursion, prolog

The Program aims at checking whether a student has taken a specified list of courses or not. But it displays false even if the student has taken that list of courses. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```erlang
 %Structure  Of facts

 %student(ID,FirstName,LastName,Advisor,CreditsPassed,GPA,CourseTakenList).
 %courses_taken(CourseId,CourseTitle, Credit,Grade, NoOfTimesRepeated).

   %Fact
   student(20135639,'Sara','Haider','Mr. Hussain Al-Arrayed',98,3.95,
   [courses_taken('ITCE418', 'PRODUCTIVITY WITH IS TECHNOLOGY',3,'A', 0),
    courses_taken('MATHS101', 'CALCULUS I', 3,'A', 0),
    courses_taken('ACC112', 'FINANCIAL ACCOUNTING I', 3, 'A', 0),
    courses_taken('ECON140', 'MICROECONOMICS', 3,'A', 0),
    courses_taken('ENGL219', 'TECHNICAL REPORT WRITING', 3,'A', 0)  ]  ).

 check_prereq([],Id):- !.
 check_prereq([course(P)]|T,Id):-
     student(Id,_,_,_,_,_, CoursesTakenList),
     member( courses_taken(P,_,_,_,_), CoursesTakenList),
     check_prereq(T,Id).
```

The following query should return true, since the student has taken those courses

```erlang
 ?- check_prereq([course('ITCE418'), course('ACC112')],20135639).
 false.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is an error: `heck_prereq(course(P)|T,Id)`. Were you intending the first argument to be a list? If so, you need brackets: `[course(P)|T]`. Without the brackets, it's just the term, `'|'(course(P), T)`. In some Prologs, like GNU, it's a syntax error.

Comment: @lurker  Yes I intended the first argument to be a list. Thanks for pointing out the syntax error. I have corrected it but the output still remains false instead of true.

Comment: @Far, you need to replace : `[course(P)]|T` with `[course(P)|T]`

Comment: @coder Yes i did in this way. but there is no difference in the output. Is the logic of the program wrong that it returns false even after correcting syntax errors ?

Comment: @Far, it seems you didn't ...check my answer.

Comment: @coder oh sorry. I got the notification late

Comment: @Far, never mind, glad to help :) !!!

Comment: @Far, your code change doesn't match what I suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace : `[course(P)]|T with [course(P)|T]`

```
 check_prereq([],_):- !.
 check_prereq([course(P)|T],Id):-
     student(Id,_,_,_,_,_, CoursesTakenList),
     member( courses_taken(P,_,_,_,_), CoursesTakenList),
     check_prereq(T,Id).
```

Also in the first line replaced `Id` with `_` (anonymous variable) in order to get rid of warnings(Singleton variable). Now it is working fine:

```
?- check_prereq([course('ITCE418'), course('ACC112')],20135639).
true ;
false.
```

Note that it returns true and asking for more solutions returns false but it succeeds as we expected.